# How do i Reboot into Bootmenu from terminal

Tags: reboot

My Laptop has this Fast boot function that i cant turn off and it just starts booting into Ubuntu instantly from a fresh start.

So im wondering is there a terminal command to reboot into the bootmenu? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is the make/model of your laptop?  From there, use Google to determine what the keypress is to enter BIOS.  After that there should be a setting to turn off the Fast Boot or at least show some information/diagnostic screen on boot.